# disable update of row in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am using spring-boot and oracle. I am processing data over kafka and a single row is update asynchronously many time updating the count over different topic listeners.

Now i want to terminate this process. Since multiple threads will be updating it. There can be chance that the status is update during this processing part. Can i handle this thing from database itself saying if a particular column's value (say status) is "TERMINATED" it should reject all the updates on this row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a database trigger during the update dml operation where upcoming value for status column should be prevented if the new column value is `TERMINATED` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Upd_Disable
BEFORE UPDATE ON tab
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.status = 'TERMINATED' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'The Process cannot be terminated !!');
  END IF;  
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=47926f4b1dcf3239b6a63db2673284a8)</kbd>

Comment: Why AFTER, and not BEFORE trigger?

Comment: doesn't matter @Littlefoot , both will do the same for this case, as you know

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to update a row, then check whether condition is violated, and - if so - raise an error? Isn't it simpler/better to *intercept* it **before** anything is done?

Comment: well, might be @Littlefoot , you mean it as a redundant operation for DBMS.

Comment: Something like you going to a football game. They let you in, you take a seat, and then they come to verify whether you have a ticket and kick you out if you don't. Instead, they *first* check your ticket and - if it is OK - let you in.

Comment: :D I think you missed the football with supporters, too ... @Littlefoot Nice example. Btw, thank you ..

Comment: Actually, I don't like football that much at all :)

Comment: If it going to raise an exception based on a column value an AFTER trigger should be preferred. With a BEFORE trigger there is the possibility that a subsequent one could employ conditions and change that value; but not if the exception has already been raised. With an AFTER trigger there can be no subsequent data modification.  Maybe a better analogy would be a train. You get on, take a seat, they come to check your ticket, but at that point you can buy one.

Comment: But my question was if my old status is "TERMINATED" no other status should be update.. i.e. i should be able update status to "TERMINATED" once and then all other status should be rejected. i.e. if the seat is "corrupted" no one should be able to book ticket. @BarbarosÖzhan your answer states that a particular status is not supported rather

Comment: it should be CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Upd_Disable
AFTER UPDATE ON tab
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.status = 'TERMINATED' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'The Process cannot be terminated !!');
  END IF;  
END;
/

Comment: change status from new to old and i will accept answer